# Rectifier Output Skewed with High Frequency input

Tags: frequency, rectifier

In our lab, we tested a half-wave and full-wave rectifier with the input being a sine function. As the frequency increased, the output began to look triangular rather than hills. I cannot find why this is so. How does increasing the frequency affect the rectifier output?

Thank you!

Comment: Diode types, frequencies, loading, schematics?

Comment: I'm not sure of the diode type (I believe just a simple plain one), but I've attached the schematic and the frequency was varied from 500Hz to 100kHz. 
https://ibb.co/fE69Nk

Answer (score 1):

With inductance, you get a constant charging current up, and then the Iload implements a constant discharge current down.